# Unable to send props to react component imported from index.esm.js file

Tags: reactjs, rollup, npm-build

I'm trying to test the build file for the npm package I wish to publish. I have used rollup to build, generated files are - index.cjs.js, index.cjs.js.map, index.esm.js. when I import the esm.js file which has my react component defined and I send props, it shows props undefined, due to which I'm unable to test the functionality. Not sure why it's happening. Here's the code-

```
import ErrorBoundary from '../src/dist/index.esm'

export default function App(){
return(
<div><ErrorBoundary
onError="Hello"
><Home/></ErrorBoundaryr></div>
)
}
```

Here's my component in esm file-

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component{
constructor (props){
super(props);
this.state={
hasError: false
};
}
```

//other part of code
}

Comment: Rather than plain text explanation, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please?

Comment: @Yogesg Yadav I've edited the question and added code snippet now. Thanks

Comment: You are passing prop to `ErrorHandler` but expecting it in `ErrorBoundary `?

Comment: @Yogesh Yadav, I must have missed changing that,. I've edited it. But I'm using the same component name in import which is there is esm file